# Get rid of subscriptions in subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to understand what RxJS flatMap does to get rid of a subscription in another subsription:

```
this.http.get<IFilm>(`https://swapi.dev/api/films/${id}/`).subscribe(res => {
  this.film = res;
  this.film.characters.map((url: string) => {
    this.http.get<IActor>(url).subscribe(res => {
      this.name = res;
      this.NameList.push(this.name)
    })
  })

});
```

What would be a good way to resolve this? Is it possible to do this in a method or should I use 2 for example or pipes like here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dlony2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstar-wars.service.ts

Comment: `mergeMap/flatMap` doesn't really get rid of an inner subscription. Most operators subscriber to some observables. But operators like `mergeMap` manage those subscriptions for you, e.g. if you unsubscribe from the outer observable they'll unsubscribe from the inner observable. Using operators is preferred as they hide and manage those inner subscriptions for you. So use `mergeMap` and `forkJoin` like in the stackblitz you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've done the RxJS thing of not putting any side effects into your transformations/data pipeline and saving them all for the end consumer (subscribe).

This should make it much easier to test, extend, and maintain your code.

Typically your end consumer should be the UI or a database of some sort. There's rarely a reason to have your end consumer just set a global variable, but that's where I left it for now.

```js
this.http.get<IFilm>(`https://swapi.dev/api/films/${id}/`).pipe(  
  map(film => ({
    film,
    nameCalls: film.characters.map(
      url => this.http.get<IActor>(url)
    )
  })),
  mergeMap(({film, nameCalls}) => forkJoin(nameCalls).pipe(
    map(names => ({film, names}))
  ))
).subscribe(({film, names}) => {
  this.film = film;
  this.nameList = names;
});
```

Comment: Your Code is an good example for me, thank you but I get errors for example for Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown or (parameter) film: unknown

Comment: AH yes, makes sense, I forgot a closing bracket on the map. Try it now

Comment: Now I get one error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: Doesn't sound like an RxJS error. Is `film.characters` a string? I assumed it was an array from how you used it in your question. This is likely specific to your implementation so I'll leave the debugging up to you

Comment: Thanks, film is a Json Response from the swapi api. I will refactor the code and post it here. Thanks again!

Comment: :), If you get it working (and you're not waiting on another answer), please remember to mark an answer as accepted. Thanks :)